# how to take change value in loop scala

Tags: scala

I can't change value of val in cycle in scala
i'm trying to write a small function like this

```
def replicate(s:Any,n:Int):List[Any] = {
    val i = 0
    var list = s::Nil
    for i<-1 to n {
       list::=s
    }
    return list 
}
```

But the usage of this function returns only one element in list (when n for example = 3)
How to fix this?

Comment: If this is an exercise in learning functional programming, look into recursion.

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting any output at all since the code you've posted won't actually compile. It's worth noting that good Scala practice almost never uses `return` (it's seldom needed), the use of `var`s is also avoided, and whenever you see type `Any` that's a pretty good sign that things aren't going well.

Comment: that code doesn't even compile...

Comment: `val` are `immutable` references. Which means you can not reassign a `val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do your task

```
def replicate(s:Any,n:Int):List[Any] = (1 to n) map (_=> s) toList
```

Example:

```
replicate("omg", 4)
List[Any] = List(omg, omg, omg, omg)
```

Comment: Simpler still: `List.fill(n)(s)` (The [Standard Library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List$) is full of hidden treasures.)

Answer (score 0):

```
def replicate(s:Any,n:Int):List[Any] = {
    val i = 0
    var list = s::Nil
    for (i<-1 to n) {
       list::=s
    }
    return list 
}
```

and I get

```
scala> replicate("lol", 5)
res0: List[Any] = List(lol, lol, lol, lol, lol, lol)
```